# Bash script reading random lines in a text file

Tags: bash, random

I have a one line bash script that reads random lines in a text file:

```
#!/bin/bash
shuf -n 1 excuses.txt
```

When I call the script, it gives me a random one-liner but I notice that the command I used in the script is really not all that random and when I run the script multiple times I may see the same line being read (even though it's random). My question is: Is there another way to randomly print a line of text that may be even more random than what I have in my code? Please note, I have a 1,000 lines that can be read from this text file.

EDIT: Here are my results when I used `shuf` to randomize the text file:

```
[root@ftpserver bofh] ./bastardScript.sh
Atilla the Hub
[root@ftpserver bofh] ./bastardScript.sh
kernel panic: write-only-memory (/dev/wom0) capacity exceeded.
[root@ftpserver bofh] ./bastardScript.sh
We had to turn off that service to comply with the CDA Bill.
[root@ftpserver bofh] ./bastardScript.sh
YOU HAVE AN I/O ERROR -> Incompetent Operator error
[root@ftpserver bofh] ./bastardScript.sh
Change in Earth's rotational speed
[root@ftpserver bofh] ./bastardScript.sh
Atilla the Hub
```

So as you can see within the time I use the script (about 6-10 times):

```
[root@ftpserver bofh] ./bastardScript.sh
Atilla the Hub
```

Comes up. I want to see if it can get anymore random than that.

Comment: `--random-source=FILE`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, how would I apply that to my code?

Comment: note: it works fine on my system.

Comment: "I may see the same line being read (even though it's random)" - that's because it's random.

Comment: Im not complaining about it not working, however I was asking if there is a way to make the lines being printed even more random.

Comment: no, you're asking the wrong question. it's (probably) already as random as it can be. rephrase what you want.

Comment: If you're going to argue that it's not random enough -- measure that! Give us some concrete evidence supporting the claim that what you're getting isn't a legitimate random distribution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, bear with me and I will. I will edit my question momentarily.

Comment: By the way -- I'd consider using `dd` to seek to a random offset into the file, reading to the next newline, and then taking the next full line from there -- retrying if you can't do both reads successfully. That's going to be much more efficient than shuffling the whole file just to get a single random line.

Comment: though, ironically, not as random (line size!)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, quite right -- that would weight based on length of the preceding line.

Comment: what you want is less random. it's like expecting a dice never to be 5 again, once you rolled 5.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, well yes I want it to appear that way. I feel like using that script and for the same line to come up within 10 times of use and when it has a 1,000 lines of text is just not all that random..

Comment: quite the opposite, but you don't care to listen. it's more random. randomness is amazingly *non-intuitive*.

Comment: @ryekayo, are you familiar with the birthday paradox? You're seeing a version of that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I am not, you mind enlightening me on it :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: Picking 10 uniformly random lines from a 1000 line file has a surprisingly high [4.5% chance](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=birthday+problem+calculator&a=FSelect_**BirthdayProblem-.dflt-&f2=10&f=BirthdayProblem.n_10&f3=1000&f=BirthdayProblem.pbds_1000) of giving a duplicate. If you pick 15 lines, the probability is 10%, and with 25 lines (a terminal screenful), one in four runs will have at least one duplicate, just by pure random coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that `shuf` is using a high-entropy source:

```
shuf -n 1 --random-source=/dev/random <excuses.txt
```

That said, what it sounds like you *really* want is to not see the same excuse twice (until they've all been consumed). That being the case, I'd consider shuffling the file once, storing a counter, and showing each line in turn.

```
# In Bash 3 or earlier, you'll need to hardcode a FD number here.
exec {lock_fd}>excuses.count
flock -x "$lock_fd"

[[ -e excuses.shuffled ]] || {
  shuf <excuses.txt >excuses.shuffled || exit
  echo 1 >excuses.count
}
[[ -s excuses.shuffled ]] || exit
counter=$(<excuses.count)
line=$(sed -n "${counter} p" <excuses.shuffled)
if [[ $line ]]; then
  echo "$line"
  echo "$((counter + 1))" >excuses.count
else
  # ran out of lines; delete files and restart this script to reshuffle
  rm -- excuses.shuffled # clear our now-used shuffle
  exec {lock_fd}<&-      # release the lock
  exec "$0" "$@"         # restart the script
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat excuses.txt | sort --random-sort | head -n 1
```

Comment: Useless use of cat: `sort --random-sort <excuses.txt | head -n 1` is a touch more efficient.

Comment: `IFS= read -r < <(sort --random-sort <excuses.txt); printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"` is arguably even more efficient, since it doesn't require an external `head` command but does that as well in native bash.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is clearly less random.

If you don't want to repeat older lines, you need some way to *remember* previous results.

What I would do is shuffle the whole file and store it somewhere.
Then each time the script is called grab the last line and remove it.
Once you detect the file is empty you have to do another shuffle.

If you worry about concurrency, you'll need proper file locking.

Comment: ...and, see, while you were _describing_ it, I was _implementing_ it. :)